# Serving laravel over HTTPs using Angular-UI

Tags: php, angularjs, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel-4

I am trying to serve Laravel 4 routes using Angular-UI over HTTPs. Without HTTPs it works but over the same it brings a 404 error.

Thanks for any assistance.

htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Route:

```
Route::get('index', array('as'=>'index','uses'=>'PagesController@getIndex'));
```

Angular-UI

```
state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'index'
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to it, I hope this helps someone. On linux do the following:

sudo leafpad etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl

Then on that file edit the following line `AllowOverride None` in

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
```

To:

```
AllowOverride all
```

Thank you all.